# Change background color of a datatable <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change `background` of a `<tr>` of a datatable which is like this.

```
var lastIdx = null;
var t = $("#campaigns_list").DataTable();

t.rows.add(['.$str_json.']).draw();

$("#campaigns_list tr").not(":first").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css("background", "yellow");
  },
  function() {
    alert("bye");
  }
);
```

But I don't know why, the `background-color` of the `<tr>` isn't changing.

```
$(this).css("background","yellow");
```

This code seems to be unable to change color. However, the hover function do call itself, cause if I am replacing the above line with an alert then the alert is happening fine.

Comment: Please post an example with the relevant code on a Snippet.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have a straightforward answer, add a snippet code please.

Comment: I cant put a code in the snippet @Qwerty.... its a whole lot of files, and its quite impossible to put so much big code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely the `<td>` inside your `<tr>` that needs to have the background color instead.

**EDIT: For example:**

```
$(this).find('td').css('background', 'yellow');
```

Comment: How do you know the `tr` element has any `td` elements at all? You shouldn't post answers to questions which need more information.

Comment: its fine, the tr has td...... can u post some code by which i can change the background of the td??? or add a class called sorting_1 to each td of the current tr??

Comment: You are right in your statement. However the jQuery Datatable-plugin generates a markup that contains `<td>`.

Comment: @Saswat post that in your question then, not here in this comment. Eric's answer here is completely pointless without that information being given in your question.

Comment: the answer is awesome... let 2 mins go, and i will accept this answer... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me this is an issue of event delegation, as this is used with `datatables`. **`Datatables`** plugin generates the `trs` dynamically and you are binding the event on page load and `trs` are getting generated after DOM has been loaded, so you can try with delegating the event to the closest static parent or document itself:

```
$("#campaigns_list").on('hover mouseenter', 'tr:not(:first)', function(){
```

or you can event try with this too:

```
$(document).on('hover mouseenter', '#campaigns_list tr:not(:first)', function(){
```

you can delegate to the *closest static parent* or to the `$(document)` itself.

Comment: Because the elements are dynamically created, you would have to bind to the parent (#campaigns_list) and then get the children (tr) - as these child tr elements are dynamic.

Comment: see when you load your page trs were not there, they were generated dynamically and with your piece of code it seems you are binding event when dom content gets loaded but trs are getting generated long after it. about alert seems to me it holds the document but as datatable has a async call so it gets loaded then all works fine.